# Create new seismic collection Ocean framework

Tags: c#, transactions, ocean, petrel

I'm trying to create a new empty seismic collection with the following snippet of code.

`Collection` is created and added to the input pane, but trying to create `NewSeismicCollection` throws up a

> A plug-in has triggered error:
>   Slb.Ocean.Core.TransactionLockException; Transaction lock failure.

```
if(seismicProj.SeismicCollectionCount == 0)
{
    PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("No seismic collections in current project");
    using (ITransaction trans2 = DataManager.NewTransaction())
    {
        trans2.Lock(proj);
        Collection col2 = proj.CreateCollection("Collection"); 
    }

    using (ITransaction txn = DataManager.NewTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            txn.Lock(seismicProj);
            SeismicCollection seisColl = seismicProj.CreateSeismicCollection(
                "NewSeismicCollection");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            txn.Commit();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be in a single transaction that you commit in the `try` block, as in:

```
using (ITransaction txn = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        txn.Lock(proj);
        Collection col2 = proj.CreateCollection("Collection"); 
        txn.Lock(seismicProj);
        SeismicCollection seisColl = seismicProj.CreateSeismicCollection("NewSeismicCollection");
        txn.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Or to figure out the error: try as two separate transactions:

```
using (ITransaction txn = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        txn.Lock(proj);
        Collection col2 = proj.CreateCollection("Collection"); 
        txn.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

using (ITransaction txn = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        txn.Lock(seismicProj);
        SeismicCollection seisColl = seismicProj.CreateSeismicCollection("NewSeismicCollection");
        txn.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Alex and Marcelo. I have tried both your suggestions but still getting Transaction lock failure..

Comment: When (i.e. at what line in the above code block) do you get this exception, and what is its message?

Comment: Thanks Alex. From the OceanPetrelException.log file, the exception is at line 7 of the above code snippet (txn.Lock(seismicProj);). So the transaction fails to lock seismic project. Is it because for a petrel project with no seismic data, there is no Seismic Project?

Comment: What is the exception message? Does your `seismicProj` have the value `null`? If not, one thing you could try is split this up into two transactions: One on the `proj` collection, and a second on the `seismicProj` collection (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

You first transaction block is missing a commit() this will cause an abandoned transaction exception and may cause your project to be in an unsupported state, which in turn may cause your transaction lock exception.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised because there was no seismic data in the project, there was no "seismicProj" so I created an empty seismic project first and it worked.